# How can I realistically test the server response of a controller that has a null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, rest

I want to write a test that evaluates the response of a controller that has a NullPointerException while handling the request.

For that purpose I wrote a controller that throws a NullPointer while handling the request. Using the MockMVC controller I send a GET request to that controller.

The controller that throws the Null Pointer while handling it:

```
@Controller
public class Controller{  

    @GetMapping(value = "/api/data")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> getData() {

        if (true)
            throw new NullPointerException(); // Intended Nullpointer Exception 

        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
}
```

The test function that I expect to receive a 500 error:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc

public class Test {

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturn500StatusWhenControllerThrowsAnException() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api/data"))
            .andExpect(status().is5xxServerError())
            .andReturn();
    }

}
```

I expect the MockMVC request to return an error 500, like the real controller does when it runs as server.
Actually instead the MockMVC just fails with a NullPointer Exception, and does not return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me using WebTestClient.

Added two new dependencies to my build.gradle:

```
testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.1.3.RELEASE"
testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.1.3.RELEASE"
```

The test function looks like that:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturn500StatusWhenControllerThrowsAnException() throws Exception {

        webTestClient.get().uri("/api/data")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().is5xxServerError();

    }

}
```

Like that the GET request returns the error 500 exactly how it does in real world conditions.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT after more information have been added to the original question:
I had the same issue, try with these annotations instead of the three you have:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
@AutoConfigureWebClient
```

Comment: Thank your for this hint. I have this in my actual code, but forgot to paste it here. So it does not work with this added either. I added it for clarity.

Comment: @Codev what is null when the NPE is thrown? The mockMvc?

Comment: Unfortunately the same problem with theses 3 annotations.

Comment: @Codev what is null debugging your test? It is working fine for me, as in the NPE is thrown in the correct line.

Comment: @burn87 it is a org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException. It occurs in at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest() and propagates up to MockMvc.perform() which I call.

Comment: @burn87 my problem is: In the real world, the API returns an error code. I want a MockMVC that returns me that same error code. Not one that propagates the Exception.

Comment: @Codev after a bit of investigation it looks like what you want is not easily achievable, you can read more about it here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7321 and here http://javaninja.net/2016/11/testing-spring-mvc-exceptions-status-codes/